# How do I pause console intpu while other method finish in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait

I have the following task in Java: 
User is writing messages to the console. I am reading this input and process it to relevant objects (books). When the number of processed books is equal to 30, I have to pause the console input, log a report with the processed books so far, and then continue receiving messages from the console. (Since it is a console application, the assumption is that it is a single threading application)

I am newbie to concurrent programming but from what I've read I need to use `wait()` and `notify()` methods.

My application structure so far is the following:

`InputReader.java` - main class which reads the input from the console and convert to the relevant object
`BookReader.java` - class, which most important method is to process a single book (while keep count of the number of books processed so far). Lets call it `public static store(Book book)`. 
So in `InputReader.java` after reading a single console line, I process it into a `Book` object and then I call `BookReader.keep(book)` (since `store` method inside `BookReader.java` calss is static).
The problem (or the part which I struggle with) is how do I pause the console after reading the 30th book, and then print an output.
From what I've read I should use `wait()` inside my `store(Book book)` method and `notify()` inside the method which will do the report.
Since `store(Book book)` is a `static` method I've read that I should use `private static final Object lock = new Object();` inside my `BookStore.java` class? So currently my structure is something like the following:

```
protected static synchronized void reader(Book book) throws InterruptedException {
        counter++;
        //some method which will keep my books into a local datastructure
        if(counter == 30) {
            LOGGER.info("The console should stop accept new input now");
            synchronized(lock){
                lock.wait();
             } 
            // my main question: do I need to call printReport() here? If not here, then where?
            report();
        }
    }
```

and the `report()` method which after it print the report, should make the console available for reading new messages:

```
private static synchronized void report() {
        synchronized(lock){
            System.out.printline("print some report here")
            }
            // I guess after the report is printed, I should use notifyAll() and that will make the console again available for reading an input?
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

Please remember that since my `store(Book book)` is static I am using `static Object lock = new Object();` as an object of the `BookReader.java` class.
My main question: do I call the `report()` method at the right place? If not there then where?

Comment: Does the application have to be multithreaded at all? Is this for some kind of excercise?

Comment: This seems to be overcomplicating the problem by quite a bit. You state that it is a single threaded app and then proceed to use multi-threading concepts. Why is a method being static relevant? Please state the actual problem you want help with instead of descibing your entire thought castle.

Comment: @Thomas no it doesnt. It was explicitly said that it is a single thread application. But I thought that I should "pause" the console input while I am outputting the report?

Comment: If this is a single threaded application then that single thread can't read any input while it is generating and printing the output, so no need for any coordination between threads (there would be only one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program reads 30 lines from the console, writes a report and repeats

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String report = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                report += sc.nextLine()+" ";
            }
            System.out.println(report);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to make a "work-around" and save all the transmissions coming during the "report time" in a collection like the queue and then read the books in the queue when u have reported the status. Mabye thats another solution of your problem.